# I can not return to PartialView by using JSON

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, json

I have been looking for return partialview by using json.However I can only see partial view's name as html.

İf Username and Password is not null , ı want to redirect to PartialView.

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index()
{
return View();
}
```

Index View:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function test() {

var veri = {
KullaniciAd: $('#KullaniciAd').val(),
Sifre: $('#Sifre').val(),
};

$.ajax({
url: "/Home/Menu",
type: "POST",
dataType: "json",
contentType: 'application/json',
data: JSON.stringify(veri),
success: function (mydata) {

$("#message").html(mydata);
},
error: function () {
$("#message").html("error");
}
});

return false;

}
</script>

<input type="text" id="KullaniciAd" name="KullaniciAd" />
<input type="password" id="Sifre" name="Sifre" />
<input type="button" onclick="test()" value="Giriş" />


<div id="message"></div>
```

My Menu ActionResult

```
 public ActionResult Menu(MyModel model)
    {
        if (model.KullaniciAd != null && model.Sifre != null)
        {
            return Json("_MenuPartial", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Have a look at my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18558280/mvc-razor-view-text-in-table-does-not-update-on-checkbox-selection/18559622?noredirect=1#comment27357117_18559622

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need render view to string

```
  public string RenderRazorViewToString(string viewName, object model)
  {
    ViewData.Model = model;
    using (var sw = new StringWriter())
    {
      var viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(ControllerContext, viewName);
      var viewContext = new ViewContext(ControllerContext, viewResult.View, ViewData, TempData, sw);
      viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);
      viewResult.ViewEngine.ReleaseView(ControllerContext, viewResult.View);
      return sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
     }
  }
```

In controller

```
var stringView = RenderRazorViewToString("_MenuPartial",model)
return Json(stringView , JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Answer (score 0):

That it because you are just returning **`_MenuPartial` - string** as `Json` data.

If you want to return `JSON`, then return `JsonResult` instead of `ActionResult`.
The below code should also work - ultimately, the browser will get `HTML` string as `ajax` call result from server

```
public ActionResult Menu(MyModel model)
{
    if (model.KullaniciAd != null && model.Sifre != null)
    {
        return View("_MenuPartial");

    }
    return null;
}
```